# check url image with case statment

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i have created an interactive report with below code

```
select
CASE '<img src="http://test.com/uploadedimages/'||:P51_PATIENT_ID||'/'||:P51_BOOK_ID||'/photo1.png">' 
when '<img src="http://test.com/uploadedimages/'||:P51_PATIENT_ID||'/'||:P51_BOOK_ID||'/photo1.png">' 
then '<img src="http://test.com/uploadedimages/'||:P51_PATIENT_ID||'/'||:P51_BOOK_ID||'/photo1.png">' 
ELSE '<img src="http://www.wellesleysocietyofartists.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/image-not-found.jpg" height="55" width="55">'end  photo1
,

decode(
'<img src="http://test.com/uploadedimages/'||:P51_PATIENT_ID||'/'||:P51_BOOK_ID||'/photo1.png">' ,
'<img src="http://test.com/uploadedimages/'||:P51_PATIENT_ID||'/'||:P51_BOOK_ID||'/photo1.png">' ,
'<img src="http://www.wellesleysocietyofartists.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/image-not-found.jpg" height="55" width="55">'
) photo2

from dual
```

first problem :
the problem is when i use case image appears successfully but when image is not exist else statement not executed  so image-not-found.jpg not appear

if i use decode else statment is always executed even if photo1.png exist

second problem :
how can i put a hyperlink for the image i tried to use HTML HREF without successfully working code

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

neither CASE nor DECODE will check if the image "exists" in that URL.

If you want to check PATIENT_ID or BOOK_ID values you don't actually need to include the whole URL in your CASE/DECODE.

You just need something like:

```
select patient_id
     , book_id
     , case
         when <boolean_condition> then 'some string here'
         when <another boolean condition> then 'other string here'
         else 'another string'
       end img_src
  from dual
```